# How to add the "hidden" attribute to, and then remove it from an existing HTML 5 element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a button that I would like to be able to make appear and disappear on the page as needed.
I can have the button hidden to begin with, using the hidden attribute.

```
<button type="button btn-primary" id="peekaboo-button" hidden>Peekaboo</button>
```

I can then have the button appear by removing the hidden attribute using the removeAttribute function in the DOM.

```
document.getElementById("peekaboo-button").removeAttribute("hidden");
```

I need to learn how to add the hidden attribute back to the button element to hide it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `hidden` attribute for that.

```
document.getElementById("peekaboo-button").hidden = true
```

This also means if you want to show it, you can set `hidden` to false

Comment: the hidden = true works for my purpose, this solves the part of the answer that I did not have. For some reason the hidden = false does not work.

Comment: no, for some reason it doesn't work that way for me. I am investigating it more to see what may be causing this issue.

Comment: @TysonGibby in what browser? Did you try my snippet?

Comment: @mplungjan I like your snippet, but I need to use the hidden attribute and not the display:none styling. I am using Chrome 88.0.4324.150

Comment: @TysonGibby My FIRST snippet works just fine in Chrome so what does it do on your computer?

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
button.hidden=true;
```

and

```
button.hidden=false;
```

[hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden)

> The HTMLElement property hidden is a Boolean which is true if the element is hidden; otherwise the value is false. This is quite different from using the CSS property display to control the visibility of an element. The hidden property applies to all presentation modes and should not be used to hide content that is meant to be directly accessible to the user.

```js
const peekaboo = document.getElementById("peekaboo-button") 
peekaboo.addEventListener("click",function() {
  const but = this;
  but.hidden=true
  setTimeout(function() {  but.hidden=false },1000)
})
```

```html
<button type="button btn-primary" id="peekaboo-button">Peekaboo</button>
```

Same but with class

```js
const peekaboo = document.getElementById("peekaboo-button") 
peekaboo.addEventListener("click",function() {
  const but = this;
  but.classList.toggle("hide"); // or add
  setTimeout(function() {  but.classList.toggle("hide") },1000)
})
```

```css
.hide { display:none }
```

```html
<button type="button btn-primary" id="peekaboo-button">Peekaboo</button>
```